# ideas for android application update

Tags: android

I'm planning to use my website to provide updates for my android application whenever the user decides to perform an update( in case there is one available) . I'm thinking to use http requests for the communication between the user and the server, so whenever there is a new update the server sents back to the user the link to download the apk of the update through the android browser. So far I think it should work !?!.  But once I have the apk of the new update on the card ,and the installed old version of the application  how do I actually perform the update ?

Comment: If you're uploading your application to the Market, you don't need to handle manual updating of your application; this is a part of the Android documentation that is out of date.

Comment: Still, there are some circumstances in which letting users know that an update is available from within the app might be useful. ie: a critical update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show an alert and send the user to your application page on the **Android Market** (or an alternative market) instead. Most users will find this method more familiar.

If you want to host apk files in your website and let users download them directly anyway, then you should configure your site to identify the apk extension as an Android package. To do this you can add the following to your **.htaccess** (assuming your web server is using Apache):

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive apk
```

If not the Android browser will not recognize the file as an Android application, and won't offer the user the choice to install it.

Comment: I 'm not sure what you mean by .htaccess ? ,could you provide info on that ? .

Comment: Apache configuration files. A brief introduction here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess

Technically, if you create an .htacess file in your web root, or edit the existing one and add that line, it should work. However, I don't recommend using .htaccess files blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to avoid using the android marketplace, I would recommend just pushing updates through the store. Getting a notification that an update is available is more user friendly than requiring manual checks for updates that may not exist. Also, the installation is taken care of for you.